# Reading specific rows from online JSON file

Tags: c#, json, .net, url

I have a below URL from which has huge amount of data so, I want to pick up only those rows which has
token = BANKNIFTY%

https://margincalculator.angelbroking.com/OpenAPI_File/files/OpenAPIScripMaster.json

Is there any way to do that with C#? I mean, I have found few code on SO which are reading whole JSON first and then doing operation on it which hanged my system.

Comment: It's a pretty simple JSON, just lots of it. You could just stream it byte by byte to build each individual object (count the open and close brace), then deserialise the individual object and process it before reading the next one.

Comment: How long did you leave it running before it hung? It's a large file so it's going to take some time to download. I just ran it on a fairly low spec machine and it took about 38 seconds to download and then 0.15 seconds to deserialise. What code did you use to deserialise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/) - an open source library to stream such elements from large JSON file as below

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
var sr = wc.OpenRead("https://margincalculator.angelbroking.com/OpenAPI_File/files/OpenAPIScripMaster.json");

using (var r = new ChoJSONReader(new StreamReader(sr)))
{
    var items = r.Where(rec1 => ((string)rec1.symbol).StartsWith("BANKNIFTY")).ToArray();
    foreach (var rec in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(rec.Dump());
    }

    Console.WriteLine(items.Length);
}
```

Sample fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hOTpIN

Disclaimer: I'm author of this library